# How to avoid adding package to node_modules if it placed locally

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have repository with app and modules. Modules includes in app by `package.json` like:

`"application-module": "file:../modules/application-module"`

After `yarn install` that dependency added to `node_modules`.

I want to make module-base application. `app` folder reproduce root module. Other modules like `admin-panel-module`, `account-module` should be in `modules` folder. So, app may have `node_modules` inside, but also `modules` folder for modules. Those modules will add by `git subtree` from another repos. So, this way I can develop independently

Is any way to avoid adding and use local directories?

Comment: What specific behavior do you mean with 'local directories'?

Comment: @Sergeon `repository-folder(-app, -modules)`
I want to use `modules` inside `app`, init new React app and be happy

Comment: So basically you want to get `node_modules` renamed to `modules` instead? Why (if that is the case)?

Comment: @Sergeon let me explain. I want to make module-base application. `app` folder reproduce root module. Other modules like `admin-panel-module`, `account-module` should be in `modules` folder. So, `app` may have `node_modules` inside, but also `modules` folder for modules. Those modules will add by `git subtree` from another repos. So, this way i can develop independently

Comment: I believe now I understand this. So you have `app/` and then some modules specific to your app, like `account-module` or `admin-module`. You want to have a `node_modules` in `app/` that handles all the **common** dependencies, but  then if `admin-module` has a dependency specific for itself, you wan't to place that depency in `node_modules` local to that module. Is that right?

Comment: @Sergeon exactly so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Multiple node_modules and package.json

In any node/npm project, you can have multiple `package.json` across your directory tree, like:

```
app/
  package.json
  node_modules
  src...
  account_module/
    package.json
    node_modules
    src...
  admin_module/
    package.json
    node_modules
    src..
```

When you invoke `yarn` (or `npm install` ofc) on any of the children modules, the dependencies listed in their local `package.json` will be installed on **the local node_modules folder**.

So basically you can solve your issue ensuring that every children has their own `package.json` with their dependencies.

Still, you **can** place common dependencies in the root `app` folder. If all your projects for instance use `lodash`, you can place the `lodash` dependency in the add's `package_json`. After performing `yarn` in the `app` folder, the `lodash` package will be installed in the app's `node_modules`.

After that, if you:

`require('lodash');`

In any of the children, they will search for `lodash` in the app's `node_modules` folder if they don't find `lodash` in their own `node_modules`.

If you don't have a root `node_modules`, you can still declare a `package.json` local to any of the submodules, and they'll have their own `node_modules`.

So maybe you may want to avoid common dependencies at all, or maybe you want to store common dependencies in the `app` folder. Npm has you covered either ways.

However, if you don't want to handle common dependencies, yet are concerned about having to store a lot of duplicated packages in local machines, you may want [to checkout pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm), which is a wrapper over npm which allows to save a lot of space in local development machines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for so detailed answer. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm having (almost) the same issue with yarn.

I have create a package (typescript) called "test". In this package, after built, there are mainly 3 directories : dist (after built), node_modules and src.

Then I have created another package "test2" and in this package, have added "test" as a dependency "yarn add c:/.../.../test".
The package is the well installed in the node_module of test2. BUT, in "test2/node_modules/test", I can find the node_modules of test ( "test2/node_modules/test/node_modules". Why ? It increases the size of the package a lot.

In both tsconfig.json (test and test2) node_modules is excluded...

thks